# Using .replace() in an eventListener to change some text, can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, methods, replace, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get to grips with how methods and regexp work within HTML. So basically all I want to do is... When I click the button, I want to use the .replace(REGEXP) method to change the word 'change' to 'keep' within the paragraph above.

Can someone explain to me why it isn't working? I'm still pretty new to this...

```js
 let x = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML;
   let button = document.getElementById('button');
   button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      x = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML.replace(/change/g, 'keep');
   });
```

```html
<p id="change">Here's an example sentence we want to change</p>
<button id="button">Change</button>
```

Not even sure if it's possible but maybe someone could point me in the right direction.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign modified text to `x` variable which is exactly only `string`. It's not reference.
You have to use `element.innerHTML = 'some inner content'`.

```js
 const targetElement = document.getElementById('change');
 let button = document.getElementById('button');
 button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    targetElement.innerHTML = targetElement.innerHTML.replace(/change/g, 'keep');
 });
```

```html
<p id="change">Here's an example sentence we want to change</p>
<button id="button">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, that's perfect! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = x.replace(/change/g, 'keep');
```

instead of

```
x = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML.replace(/change/g, 'keep');
```